# jquery input field focus out except a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm making ajax suggestion of search in which,
a suggestion box will be displayed

```
<div id="searchbox">
    <input type="text" name="search" class="searchinput"/>
</div>

<div id="sugbox">
 ......
 <a href="product.php?id=2" >Item 1</a>
 .....
</div>
```

and **Javascript**

```
$('#searchbox .searchinput').focus(
 function () {
    $('#searchbox #sugbox').show();
 });

 $('#searchbox .searchinput').focusout(
 function () {
    $('#searchbox #sugbox').hide();
 });
```

The suggestion box will open if the search textbox `#searchbox .searchinput` is `focus` and hide if `focusout`.
Problem : whenever i'm clicking the link on suggestion box, the suggestion box hides (because of input focusout event).

How can i check if the target div is the suggestion box so don't hide the box
ex ..

```
 $('#searchbox .searchinput').focusout(
 function () {
    if(target div is not sugbox)
        $('#searchbox #sugbox').hide();
 });
```

Comment: You can put the #sugbox as child div into the #searchbox ord you can make an if statement into the focusout of the .searchinput, so its only hidden, when the focus is not in eiter the searchbox or the sugbox

Comment: you want to do it in id only or you can do it on class? like <div id="sugbox"> to <div class="sugbox">?

Answer (score 5):

try to assign a class to sugbox at hover class

```
 $(".searchinput").focus(function(){
   $("#sugbox").show();
});
$(".searchinput").focusout(function(){
   if(!$("#sugbox").hasClass("hovered"))
   $("#sugbox").hide();
});
 $("#sugbox").hover(function(){
   $(this).addClass("hovered");
},function(){
   $(this).removeClass("hovered");
 });
```

here is example at jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kyawlay/9wg49L2b/5

Comment: buggy code !!! once input focused, then box hovered, click the box and then focus out input box .. it will not hide

Comment: this is because inputbox focusout event already triggered on suggect box click event. it's not complete, just solution for your purpose. actually, you should handle body click event for hiding suggect box within which, you should check input box focus state and suggect box hover state.

Comment: I updated jsfiddle example for this issues. you can try it http://jsfiddle.net/kyawlay/9wg49L2b/5/

Answer (score 1):

add a mousedown handler (triggerd before focusout/blur I think) on the box also, set a flag to true when clicked, then check this flag before hidding

```
var boxClicked = false;
$('#mainsearch .searchinput').mousedown(// listen click handler
 function () {   boxClicked = true;});
$(document).mousedown(// reset boxclicked
 function () {   boxClicked = false;});

$('#searchbox .searchinput').focus(
 function () {
    $('#searchbox #sugbox').show();
 });

 $('#mainsearch .searchinput').focusout(
 function () {
    if(!boxClicked)   $('#mainsearch #sugbox').hide();// add condition
 });
```

Comment: sorry .. i'd wrote `#mainsearch` with mistake .. it is `#searchbox`

Comment: anyway set the selectors you wish, it is just a way of doing, arrange it your way

Comment: this is a right solution, you just have to try understand it and ONLY change the selector for your needs, wanna my sandwich also ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong selector. Check this demo. http://jsfiddle.net/m711LLwr/

```
$('#searchbox #sugbox').show();
```

Should be

```
$('#mainsearch #sugbox').show();
```

Comment: sorry .. i'd wrote `#mainsearch` with mistake .. it is `#searchbox`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, What it does is when searchinput loses focus then if sugbox has no class 'NoHide', then hide it.
On body on click event, the NoHide class is assigned to sugbox if click target is not searchinput and not sugbox and not sugbox anchor.

If event target is not in above 3 mentioned selectors then remove class NoHide. I have a fiddle but I want you to try in your page as fiddle will confuse you( as it has iframe and body area of fiddle is limited).

```
$('#searchbox .searchinput').focus(
 function () {

    $('#sugbox').show();
 });

 $('#searchbox .searchinput').focusout(
 function (event) {
        if(!$('#sugbox').hasClass('NoHide'))
        $('#sugbox').hide();
 });

$('body').on('click',
 function (event) {

    if(!$(event.target).is(".searchinput") && !$(event.target).is("#sugbox a") &&  !$(event.target).is("#sugbox")){
        $("#sugbox").hide().removeClass('NoHide');
    }else
    {
      $("#sugbox").show().addClass('NoHide');
    }
 });
```